# Should I use the name "Enter" or "Return" key?

Tags: keyboard, documentation

I'm trying to list the what various keys do inside the documentation for my CLI program, but I'm not sure what to refer to this key as. It is commonly referred to as either <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>, but which is considered better UX? I was going to list it as <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd>, but that seems sloppy.

A Google search seems to indicate that `Enter` is more prevalent. However, my laptop gives different results - while having both `enter` and `return` on it, `return` is printed in larger text on the key and is placed closer on the key to the user.

How should I refer to this key?

Comment: just be consistent

Comment: If it's a CLI program, it's a fair bet the people using it will understand either term. Myself, like most of the answers, I'd go with `Enter`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To be frank, only a selected few are aware that the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd> keys are not the same - whether you refer to it as <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>, users will press either buttons (if they have both buttons). This is due to the fact that on very few software products the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd> keys do different things (Avid's Pro Tools is the only example I can give).

My own experience is that <kbd>Enter</kbd> is a more popular name; "Press the return key" sounds odd, while "Press Enter" sounds natural. I fail to see anyone to whom you'll say "Press Enter" going "Hu?", while I can imagine this happening if you'll say "Press Return". But that's just me and based on my own subjective experience; perhaps in Norway they use <kbd>Return</kbd> more than <kbd>Enter</kbd>. However, as you said, a search for "Press Enter" on Google yields 15 million results, while "Press Return" yields less than a million.

If I had been you I wouldn't worry about it so much and use <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

### Trivia

The term <kbd>Return</kbd> is a shorthand for <kbd>Carriage Return</kbd>.

Originally, the term *carriage return* referred to a mechanism or lever on a typewriter. It was used after typing a line of text and caused the assembly holding the paper (the carriage) to return to the right so that the machine was ready to type again on the left-hand side of the paper.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).

Comment: The extra trivia is quite interesting and clarifies the origins - thanks for returning (hah, get it?) to add it!

Comment: Many keyboards combine both "enter" and "return" into the same button. Here's one: http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1171/Pasted%20Graphic.png

Comment: Just a random note, Photoshop differentiates when editing text between [Enter] as a line break / carriage return, where-as the [Return] button commits your text. Just noting because Adobe's tools are a bit more widely used, and it might even be useful for some people to hear about this.

Comment: On a standard keyboard (IBM Model M) Carriage Return is to the right of the main key area and Enter is to the right of the keypad.  It's called 'enter' because it's designed for single handed data entry using the keypad.

Answer (score 29):

"Enter" is a more popular choice than "Return". [According to Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=press+the+enter+key%2Cpress+the+return+key%2Cpress+enter%2Cpress+return&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

[image]

As Robusto commented, you need to take into account that the phrases used in this ngrams search may appear in contexts other than that of computer keyboard usage and that this may skew the results. (*members of the press enter the courtroom*)

However it seems clear that Enter is a better bet than Return.

I'd therefore write *"Press Enter"* unless I could be certain that the users have a specific keyboard with a specific label on the key  want them to use.

Comment: This ignores other uses for "enter key" and "return key" such as "enter key results" and so forthy; you can get closer to the truth by making the phrase larger and more explicitly related to keyboards in order to isolate the usages. [See this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hit+the+enter+key%2Chit+the+return+key&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chit%20the%20enter%20key%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chit%20the%20return%20key%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Robusto: I incorporated your suggestion (this old 2014 answer was getting new views recently so I revised it)

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Return</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> are different keys. <kbd>Return</kbd> often found as the main key, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the numeric key.

Few software makes a difference between these. In Adobe Photoshop while editing text, <kbd>Return</kbd> will add a new line, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> will finish the editing.

Microsoft Windows on screen keyboard uses <kbd>Enter</kbd> to describe both keys; but they still act as their corresponding key. Looking at several photos of keyboards for Windows, they often have the main key as <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd> (the ↵ symbol stands for return), and just <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the numeric key.

Apple Mac keyboard uses <kbd>Return</kbd>, with <kbd>Enter</kbd> written above to be accessed by the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

Prefereably to use <kbd>Enter</kbd> for Windows and <kbd>Return</kbd> for Mac; as long as there's no difference between <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> in your software.

Answer (score 6):

What is the target platform for your CLI application? This should guide your decision.

<kbd>Enter</kbd> is more common on non-Apple keyboards.

<kbd>Return</kbd> is the standard for Apple keyboards with 'enter', as you point out, sometimes written about the key.

A third incarnation is simple using an icon on the key:

[image]

If you use a single word to describe the key, you should use the label used most often for your target platform. 'Enter' for Windows/Unix, 'Return' for OSX.

You could also, in the introduction to your instructions, place the phrase similar to:

> The 'Enter'/'Return' key, hereinafter referred to as the 'Return' key.

... or 'Enter', depending on your target platform.

Comment: The symbol on the key (it's the same on my keyboard) is quite suggestive of the historical, carriage return or return nomenclature, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

The Human Interface Guidelines (HIG) of the operating system of your program might give you a hint or the answer. There are HIG for Windows, macOS, Android and some more. For Linux things are a bit more complicated AFAIK.

For Windows:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742465.aspx
Refers to "Enter" to submit the data.

For macOS:
https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/user-interaction/keyboard/
Refers to "Return" as standard behaviour of that key, and "Enter" as result of Shift+Return. No further specification of behaviour given.

GNOME, XFCE (Linux, *nix):
https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/keyboard-input.html.en
Refers to "Return" to activate the focused UI button (= the opposite of Windows naming).

As you see, things are not that clear and it depends on the target platform which name to use.

Comment: If there is a mention, could you please cite specific instances?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding slightly on [Evil Closet Monkey's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/54464/98732), the key on the right of Apple keyboards is unambiguously the <kbd>return</kbd> key. Some older Apple keyboards, and the current [Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-english-usa), have a separate <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

You can type enter using the combination <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Enter</kbd> *semantically* makes more sense than <kbd>Return</kbd>. "Enter" corresponds to *entering data* for data entry. "Return" is a vestige from the "carriage return" of typewriters, a concept I would not expect most people today to know or understand.  Nowadays "Return" conceivably even could be confused with a <kbd>Back</kbd> button.

Answer (score 0):

It is understood either way.

Looking at the [usage of a phrase that is specific to the context of a keyboard](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hit+the+enter+key%2Chit+the+return+key&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#) up to the year 1989 "return" was favored but got overtaken by "enter" and shortly thereafter the phrase fell out of usage altogether it seems.

[image]

It's easy to sidestep the issue by simply using ⏎ , which is the [return symbol](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23ce/index.htm).
One line down and returning to the beginning of the line on the left.

Comment: Why are you using the 2012 English corpus? That's why you're results are so weird (i.e. usage converges to 0 like the world ended in 2012). The 2019 corpus gives different results.

Answer (score -4):

RETURN is a better word to use than ENTER. Primarily because of abusive illegal invasion.

ASCII has D base 15+ listed as the CTRL code for CODE RETURN. Can't find the CTRL CODE for ENTER.

ASCII 245 is cool, §§§ ASCII 189 is ¢¢¢.

ALPHA SALOME SMITH NO-ONE CODER, AKA NOX

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! I'm not sure what to make of your answer - you obviously prefer "Return", but for no obvious reason (please be aware that this site is international, and funny English words may be unintelligible for the large majority of readers).